# How do you build a Linux Kernel for Android from the AOSP?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, android-source, android-10.0

I've found that AOSP `build.sh dist` creates:

- XML files:

  ```
  ./out/soong/.intermediates/kernel/configs/q/android-4.19/kernel_config_q_4.19/gen/conditional.xml
  ./out/soong/.intermediates/kernel/configs/q/android-4.19/kernel_config_q_4.19/matrix.xml
  ```

  from the kernel config files:

  ```
  kernel/configs/q/
  ├── android-4.14
  │   ├── android-base-conditional.xml
  │   ├── android-base.config
  │   ├── Android.bp
  │   ├── android-recommended-arm64.config
  │   ├── android-recommended-arm.config
  │   ├── android-recommended.config
  │   └── android-recommended-x86.config
  ├── android-4.19
  │   ├── android-base-conditional.xml
  ... ...
  ```
- A whole copy of the Linux kernel directory in:

  ```
  out/target/product/sdm660_64/obj/kernel/msm-4.14
  ```

This newly-created `msm-4.14` includes a `.config` file which looks like normal kernel configuration.

How can I compile this kernel for `aarch64`?

When I use `make` it prompts to regenerate an `x86_64` config file, as `.config` correctly contains Aarch64 settings.

Perhaps I'm trying the wrong thing, but `mm` in `kernel/msm-4.14` ignored changes to kernel configs, and `build.sh dist` took hours.

I want to be able to change kernel configuration and source code, and build new kernels in just a few minutes, as I can for desktop machines.

How should I do this for Android?

Comment: Please check if you can compile the kernel as described [here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels-deprecated#building).

`cd <aosp_root_dir>/kernel/msm-4.4/ &&
export CROSS_COMPILE=<aosp_root_dir>/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- &&
export ARCH=arm64 &&
make sdm660_defconfig &&
make`

Comment: @Lakindu I needed to `make vendor/sdm660_defconfig` instead.  The kernel build is currently running...

Comment: @Lakindu It failed with: `./include/linux/fs.h:3309:56: warning: format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
error, forbidden warning: fs.h:3309`

Comment: @Lakindu `make bootimage -j4` works correctly (without failing as above) and responds to changes I make to the linux source code.  I think something more is needed to just build the kernel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to compile the kernel for your hardware and create the boot image :

```sh
$ cd <aosp_root_dir>
$ source ./build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch <product_name>-<build_variant>
# Example: lunch sdm660_64-userdebug

$ make bootimage -j4
# This compiles the kernel and copies it to 
# <aosp_root_dir>/out/target/product/<product_name>/kernel,
# and creates boot image at 
# <aosp_root_dir>/out/target/product/<product_name>/boot.img
```

If you still need to reduce the time it takes, then you have to find the individual commands that AOSP build system executes to compile the kernel and create the boot image.

You can find the commands from `<aosp_root_dir>/out/verbose.log.gz`. It is the compressed package that contains the verbose log of your last build.
So, build the boot image using `make bootimage` command first, then extract the `verbose.log.gz` package and you will get `verbose.log` file.

Inside that file, find a log line that contains the text : `defconfig`, and that would most probably be the command that AOSP build system executes to compile the kernel.

In my case, these 2 are the commands I found from `verbose log`, which is used to compile the kernel :

```sh
# make sdm660_defconfig
${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/make -j1 \
    -C kernel/msm-4.4 \
    O=${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/obj/kernel/msm-4.4 \
    HOSTCC=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc \
    HOSTAR=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-ar \
    HOSTLD=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-ld \
    HOSTCFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" \
    HOSTLDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" \
    ARCH=arm64 \
    CROSS_COMPILE=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- \
    sdm660_defconfig

# make
${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/make -j4 \
    -C kernel/msm-4.4 \
    O=${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/obj/kernel/msm-4.4 \
    HOSTCC=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc \
    HOSTAR=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-ar \
    HOSTLD=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.17-4.8/bin/x86_64-linux-ld \
    HOSTCFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" \
    HOSTLDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" \
    ARCH=arm64 \
    CROSS_COMPILE=${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
```

After compiling the kernel using above commands, according to `verbose log` it copies the compile output to `<aosp_root_dir>/out/target/product/<product_name>/kernel`. That is the kernel files used to create the boot image.

```sh
cp "${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/obj/kernel/msm-4.4/arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz" \
    "${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/kernel"
```

Finally, you can find the command that creates the boot image. According to my `verbose log`, following was the command :

```sh
${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/out/host/linux-x86/bin/mkbootimg  \
    --kernel ${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/kernel  \
    --ramdisk ${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/ramdisk-recovery.img \
    --cmdline "console=ttyMSM0,115200,n8 androidboot.console=ttyMSM0 earlycon=msm_serial_dm,0xc170000 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 ehci-hcd.park=3 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 sched_enable_hmp=1 sched_enable_power_aware=1 service_locator.enable=1 swiotlb=1 loop.max_part=7 buildvariant=eng veritykeyid=id:`openssl x509 -in build/target/product/security/verity.x509.pem -text | grep keyid | sed 's/://g' | tr -d '[:space:]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/keyid//g'`" \
    --base 0x00000000 \
    --pagesize 4096 \
    --os_version 10 \
    --os_patch_level yyyy-mm-dd \
    --header_version 1 \
    --output  ${ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT}/boot.img
```

Like this, you can find the commands to compile the kernel for your hardware and create the boot image.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I've awarded the bounty to this answer (as it was expiring) and I'll accept this answer once I've tested it, which may be next week.

Comment: @fadedbee, Thank you for the bounty. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  The code in my log was a very complex, with lines over 7,000 characters long.  This explains why simple attempts at kernel builds failed.